# How to make regex pattern lazy, or how to stop matching on first occurrence?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make my entire regex pattern lazy, instead of greedy, in C#. In PHP, there's the `U` option that makes the matching lazy. I don't see an equivalent setting in C#.

The pattern that I'm using is `^(.+)\(?([^)]+)\)(.*)$`, with the following example data ...

```
 BILYARD    (2): Reviewed data.
BHAT-A (1): Reviewed data.
BEEL/RUBIN (1): Emails with engagement (haha)team and OGC.  Reviewed data.          
 BILLY BOB (1hr) Mwahaha
```

If we look at how this works on regex101.com, we can see the matches: https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/3

That third line matches up to the 2nd set of parenthesis, instead of stopping at the first set. How can I make this lazy, or just stop matching at the first set of parens?

Comment: Regex101 uses PCRE syntax, not .NET Regex syntax. There _may_ be differences.

Comment: but there is only a little difference between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(.+?)\(([^)]+)\)(.*)$

   ^^
```

Here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/4

Comment: Oh man, ok so lazy operator in the correct spot seems to be the answer. Thanks! :)